# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long while locating data by pandas UInt64Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe 'df' with an UInt64Index:

> df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
UInt64Index: 132 entries, 3377906280028510514 to 9377906289175510514
Columns: 132 entries, 3377906280028510514 to 9377906289175510514
dtypes: float64(132)
memory usage: 142.2 KB
```

When i try to locate the row with the last index value 9377906289175510514(which has not reached 2**64 - 1), an OverflowError is encoutered:

> df.loc[9377906282776510514]

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1432                 key = self._convert_scalar_indexer(key, axis)
-> 1433                 if not ax.contains(key):
   1434                     error()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in contains(self, key)
   1661         try:
-> 1662             return key in self._engine
   1663         except TypeError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.__contains__()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt64HashTable.__contains__()

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on your sys.maxsize

```
import sys
print (sys.maxsize)

#9223372036854775807
```